# Always visible qml

Tags: qt, widget, symbian, visibility, qml

I have qml button file that I want to be visible above the keyboard when the keyboard is visible.

I just want to know what I should do with my QmlApplicationViewer so that my small qml block is always visible on top of all other applications but you should still have access to the application below.

I have already implemented a way for the file to become visible when the keyboard is visible and I can easily get it right above the keyboard later but now I am struggling to prevent it from stealing focus and closing the keyboard, because the moment a keyboard is opened my button appears and the keyboard closes. The moment I close my app the button disappears and the keyboard reopens in the app where I originally opened it. I want this to be a background task which supplements the keyboard functionality, the button will allow for speech input.

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.symbian 1.1

Button{
    signal keyActive()

    x: 0
    y: 0
    text: "Voice"
    property bool bob: inputContext.visible
    onBobChanged: console.log("keyboard" + bob), bob ? keyActive() : null
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsObject>

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/topwidget/main.qml"));

    viewer.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    viewer.setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
    viewer.move(10, 20);
    viewer.releaseKeyboard();
    viewer.show();

    QObject *rootObject = viewer.rootObject();
    QObject::connect(rootObject, SIGNAL(keyActive()), &viewer, SLOT(raise()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

PS. I do know when the keyboard opens and closes, all I want to know is how to display my button without the keyboard automatically closing?

Comment: Can't you install an event filter, or subscribe to the keyboard event in some way. Then once you get intrrupted by state changes in the keybaord - you can deal with it accordingly: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?235025-Qt-N97-Detecting-keyboard-open

Comment: Yes but what I'm asking is how to deal with it?

Comment: Do you  have any idea how I can deal with it once I know that the keyboard is active?

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating `x` and `y` but what you want is to control overlap, which is `z`. So you can affect what is always on top by giving it a special `z` value. See here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-item.html#z-prop

Comment: This seems to be only relative for drawing inside Viewer but does not have an affect on the position of the viewer itself relative to the rendering components of other applications and those of the operating system